# How to solve a call to click button without an alert on key down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" name="name" onkeydown="test(event)"  />

function test(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
          $("#myButton").click();  
          return false;     
        }
}
```

It's not working as expected this way, but if I add an alert to the code like this:

```
function test(event){
        alert("Why?!");
        if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
           $("#myButton").click();  
           return false;     
        }
}
```

My button is this into gsp file:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="myButton" value="Submit">
                    Button
                </button>
```

My form is this:

```
<g:form name="searchForm" controller="party" action="searchObject" class="form-horizontal margin-bottom-20">

</g:form>
```

Then everything works...
Someone can tell me what's going on and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what browser are you using ?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/qcp68fyt/ and check ur console

Comment: Juan, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @Sushil, Appears all the console outputs...

Comment: where is your button click event?

Comment: have you tried `$('form').submit();` instead of `$("#myButton").click();`?

Comment: Just found the reason for that here... My button was without the id tag. I just don't understand why by adding an alert it works... I just updated the link you sent me before and you can check it here too... http://jsfiddle.net/qcp68fyt/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name" onkeydown="test(event)" />
<button id="myButton">Button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var test = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#myButton").click();
        return false;
    }
}

$(function () {
    $("#myButton").click(function () {
        alert("This button was clicked using the enter key");
    });
});
```

If i understood correctly, you are trying to invoke a click event with a key press (in this case, the enter key). Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jsu2jsx8